# angular is not defined error in windows device but in iPad working fine

Tags: angularjs, vscode-debugger

We have a simple html file with angular.js. This is working fine in IPad device, but in windows app it is not working, when attached VScode debugger showing error: angular is not defined
[image]

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<div ng-app="spicyApp1" ng-controller="SpicyController">
<button ng-click="chiliSpicy()">Chili</button>
<button ng-click="jalapenoSpicy()">Jalapeño</button>
<p>The food is {{spice}} spicy!</p>
</div>

</html>
```

app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('spicyApp1', []);
myApp.controller('SpicyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.spice = 'very';
    $scope.chiliSpicy = function() {
        $scope.spice = 'chili';
    };

    $scope.jalapenoSpicy = function() {
        $scope.spice = 'jalapeño';
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a jquery script before the angular script.

use this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

//below you add your angular script

<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: @xyz please create a plunkr

Comment: Hi @Jazib please find the plunker link: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/xvJ1VxjJFSa0XVWt

Comment: Hi @Jazib here is the plunker link: [link](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/xvJ1VxjJFSa0XVWt)